# uncaught syntaxerror unexpected token U JSON on the server but not in localhost

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, localhost, local-storage

The code that shows the path, where user previously was, works on my localhost but when I share it with others and send it to the server they get this error: uncaught syntax error unexpected token U JSON on the server but not in localhost.  I think it cannot catch the information from local storage (which is in a browser) so we get unknown and that is why json cannot parse this info. I looked several similar solutions but nothing helped. 
maybe someone also had troubles with local storage and getting data from it.
the code:

```js
$(function() {
 
 // waiting until elem in loaded
 waitForElement("#pageHeading",function(){
     run();
 });
 
 
 function run() {
  var parameters = window.location.search;
  var parameterArray = [];
  
  // split url which starts from '?' and put it in array  
  for(var i = 1; i<=parameters.split("&").length-1; i++){
   var paramHelp = parameters.split("&")[i];
   var parameter = paramHelp.split("=")[1];
   parameterArray.push(parameter);
  }
  
  // getting path (e.g.'folder/subfolder/subfolder') and putting each part in array
  var uploadPath = parameterArray[1].substring("/documentLibrary".length);
  var uploadPath = uploadPath.replace("%20", " ");
  var path = uploadPath.slice(1).split('/');
  
  // getting current folder name
  var siteShortName = parameterArray[0];
  var folderPath = parameterArray[1];
  var currentFolderName = parameterArray[2];  
  
  // saving header text to local storage 
  var $bread = $('#bread');
  var $header = $('#pageHeading');
  var titleData = JSON.parse(localStorage.titleData);
  var abbr = window.location.href.split('&path=')[0].split('?&')[1].split('=')[1];
  console.log(path,$header.text());
  if (path.length === 1) localStorage.lastFolderName = $header.text() ;
  var lastFolderName = localStorage.lastFolderName;
  
  // creating basic breadcrumbs html elements
  $bread.append(createA("main-menu-bpp", 'main-menu-bpp', 'You are here: Main menu'))
   .append('<span> > </span>')
   .append(createA("sites-bpp", 'sites-bpp', 'Sites'))
   .append('<span> > </span>')
   .append(createA("site-home-bpp",'site-home-bpp?siteName='+siteShortName,titleData[abbr]))
   .append('<span> > </span>')
   .append(createA("doclib-bpp",'doclib-bpp?&siteName='+siteShortName, titleData[abbr]))
   .append('<span> > </span>')
   .append(createA("doclib-bpp",'doclib-children-bpp?&siteName='+siteShortName+'&path=/documentLibrary/'+path[0]+'&currFolder='+path[0],lastFolderName));
  
  // creating subfolders
  if (path.length > 1) {
   $bread.append('<span> > </span>');
   var  href = 'http://localhost:8081/share/page/doclib-children-bpp?&siteName='+abbr+'&path=/documentLibrary/'+path[0]+"/";
   for (var i=1; i < path.length; i++) {   
    if (i>1) href += '/' + path[i];
    else href += path[i];
    $bread.append(createA( path[i],href + '&currFolder=' + path[i],"Documents of Subfolder " + path[i]));
    if (i != path.length - 1) $bread.append('<span> > </span>');
   }
  }
  
  // create <a> with params =)
  function createA(id,link,tpl) {
    return $('<a/>',{
    id: id,
    href: link,
    text: tpl
   });
   
  }
 } 
 // check if element is loaded
 function waitForElement(elementPath, callBack){
   window.setTimeout(function(){
     if($(elementPath).length){
       callBack(elementPath, $(elementPath));
     }else{
       waitForElement(elementPath, callBack);
     }
   },500)
 } 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Does your `localStorage.titleData` has any data in your server?

Comment: yes, it has exactly links that should be caught. Additionally, the thing is that   we share files (git) and from my pc this script works but from other pc, localhost also, they have the same error. I cannot understand why it works only from my localhost, the code is the same actually =(

Comment: Can you quickly do a `console.log(abbr)` in both your `localhost` and in `server` and see if both matches?

Comment: from my localhost sent later, this is from [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bw-n5VzzQMo-VEdJUmRzZXZzZ0k)

Comment: and this two [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bw-n5VzzQMo-djlWdGNzSDhUc3c) , [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bw-n5VzzQMo-VEdJUmRzZXZzZ0k)

Comment: I suspect that the problem is that localStorage.titleData are not defined here, so the question is how then this data defined here

Comment: Hmm.. Looks strange. Can you please try clearing your browser cache by doing a `CTRL+SHIFT+DELETE` and refresh the page to see if it is working?

Comment: now I got the same error. I think the titleData are not defined. How I could get this information from local storage then and why it worked earlier and now not .....I cannot get it...

Comment: Okay.. Do this, In your browser (while viewing your site in Server), Press F12 and in the console type, `if(localStorage){console.log('Yes, it has support for localstorage');}else{console.log('No support for localstorage');}`

Comment: Execute the above statement in your console, and check if it returns yes or no

Comment: Yes and then again undefined